# Solving integrated squared density derivative with integration by parts

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I'm trying to understand why

$\int f^{(s)}(x)^2 dx = (-1)^s \int f^{(2s)}(x)f(x) dx$

is valid (under sufficient smoothness assumptions on $f$ where $f$ is the density of some sample). It should be solved by using integration by parts, but I don't see why all the terms disappear - for example for $s=1$ the right side would be $f'(x)f(x) - \int f''(x)f(x)dx$ but the first term isn't necessarily equal to zero. Can someone help?

I got this from Wand & Jones "Kernel Smoothing". In the beginning of the chapter it says that they assume $f$ to be "sufficiently well-behaved for all arguments involving differentiability and integrability assumptions to be valid" -  is this just applying or am I missing something?

Comment: Try putting in _limits_ to your integrals and consider why $f^\prime$ necessarily approaches $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: So it's acceptable to use limits although it's an improper integral?

Comment: _You_ are the one who typed in the integral equality and claimed that it is from a book to which many readers will not have access. Whether the result has been copied completely and correctly (e.g. did you not bother typing in the limits because you thought they are unimportant?) , or whether some conditions stated in the text immediately preceding this equality have been ignored and not included in your question is something that we cannot determine.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Further conditions have not been made, it just says "under strong assumptions".

Comment: Consider the density function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(1+\cos x\right)\mathbf 1_{x: x\in [-\pi,\pi]}$ so that $f^\prime(x) = -\frac{\sin x}{2\pi}\mathbf 1_{x: x\in [-\pi,\pi]}$ and  $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = -\frac{\cos x}{2\pi}\mathbf 1_{x: x\in [-\pi,\pi]}$.